# ^ doesn't update in repeating command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to fly in minecraft. However, the command block isn't updating my rotation. Could someone help me? I'm using this command in a repeating command block:

```
/tp @s ^ ^ ^0.5
```

Comment: Can you include the command you are trying to use?

Comment: /tp @s  ^ ^ ^0.5 PS i am on 1.16.5rc1

Comment: *@p* i am on single player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command, `/tp @s ^ ^ ^0.5` is being run in a command block. `@s` always refers to the executor, that is, the "thing" running the command.

Since your command is running in a command block, the "thing" running the command is the server. So, `@s` would not refer to you.

---

You can use `/execute` to change who the command is being executed as, like so:

`execute as @p run tp @s ^ ^ ^0.5`

This makes the nearest player run the command. If you try this, you will find that it works- sort of.

---

What does `tp @s ^ ^ ^0.5` do, exactly? It teleports the target 0.5 blocks forward. However, the command is being executed *at* the command block, so you will be teleported 0.5 blocks in front of it. To combat this, we need to change *where* the command is being executed, like so:

`execute as @p at @s run tp @s ^ ^ ^0.5`

Now you can "fly" in Minecraft.

Comment: I did that, but it isnt updating my rotation

Comment: this will only work in the 4 cardinal directions, due to command limitations.

Comment: ^ does forward nomater what

Comment: @MinecraftHacker If it still doesn't work, then I'd suspect that your command block is not activating for some reason.

Comment: @MinecraftHacker this command **should** move you forward, what do you want it to do/think it should do?

Comment: @Penguin exactly that.

Comment: I want it to update the forward direction.

Comment: Sorry for being 11 months late